# How can I start trying to solve currently unsolved math problems?

Tags: problem-solving, factoring, learning

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I really do want some guidance on this.

I really wanted to start helping solve unsolved math problems. (Like integer factoring, discrete log, etc. but I do want to expand to other problems too) How could I get a grasp of how far a particular problem is to being solved? How can I get a grasp of what math skills I would need to start solving a particular problem? Are there any good resources for problems like factorization?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization and see how much of it you understand.  Then try some of the references

Comment: [This one is interesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most if not all open questions in mathematics have at least some previously published work that can be found through a standard literature review.  In fact, the first step in doing any kind of mathematical research is literature review, which addresses all of your questions:

0. Does this problem have a name?  What do people call this problem?
1. What is the current state of knowledge regarding this problem or topic?
2. What are the mathematical prerequisites for research in this area?
3. Who has worked on the problem should I want to collaborate or ask questions?

If you do not know how to perform this type of scholarly review, then you're probably not in a position to make progress on most open questions, especially the more well-known ones.  It is **exceedingly** rare that someone, either due to age, lack of prior experience, or lack of access to published research, can make meaningful headway on such problems in complete isolation.  Even when young and inexperienced but extremely talented mathematicians make significant breakthroughs (one of which recently happened in the field of Ramsey theory), such discoveries do not occur in an intellectual vacuum.

Comment: Hey I totally get where you're coming from, I get it's difficult. I haven't done literature review yet, but it's definitely something I'm willing to do. 

One big reason I asked this question, is because I want to make sure I know what I need to do first and foremost to even start breaking into some of these problems. That was one primary motivation behind asking my question, because I really do want to start working on some of these problems. I may not be in that position now, but I want to get to that position ultimately.

Comment: @amarioguy I think the process of trying to read the literature, realizing you need to study some topic in more detail and repeating will probably be a rewarding one and give you scaffolding towards approaching some of these problems, but I don't think you should approach this from the perspective of trying to solve a specific problem, because you'll likely be dissapointed. Instead, find an area that you find compelling in its own right.